# JPA how to persist parent in bi-directional ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Payment entity with bi-directional ManyToOne releshionship to Account.

```
@Table(name="account")
public class Account implements Serializable { 

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Payment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="account",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Payment> payments;

@Table(name="payment")
public class Payment implements Serializable { 

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Account
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="idAcc")
    private Account account;
```

Account entity was persisted. And I see information about that in the browser and in database:

> Account [idAcc=475, account=12345678901230, isLock=N, rest=10000.5]

Then I need to persist child (Payment entity) and simultaneously change Account entity (change account rest). I use this code.

```
    public class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

        protected Class<T> type; 
        protected EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

        public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> type, EntityManagerFactory emf) { 
            this.emf = emf;
            this.type = type;       
        } 

        @Override
        public void create(T entity) throws Exception { 
            EntityManager em = null; 
            try { 
                em = getEntityManager();
                em.getTransaction().begin();  
                em.persist(entity); 
                em.getTransaction().commit(); 
            } 
...
@Override
    public T findById(String id) {
         EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
            try {
                Query query = em.createNamedQuery(type.getSimpleName()+".findByName");
                query.setParameter("id", id);
                return (T)query.getSingleResult();
            } finally {
                em.close();
            }
    }
```

And

```
daoPayments = new GenericDaoImpl(Payment.class,factory); 
            Payment payment = null;
                try {
                    payment = new Payment();
                    payment.setDescription("Shop 'Pirasmani'");
                    payment.setSumm(50.25);
                        Account account = (Account)daoAccount.findById(listAccount.get(0).getIdAcc());
                        account.setRest(account.getRest()-payment.getSumm());
                        payment.setAccount(account);
                        account.getPayments().add(payment);

                    daoPayments.create(payment);
                    //print result 
                    Payment paymentMerged = (Payment)daoPayments.read(payment);
                    out.println(paymentMerged.toString()+"<br>");
```

Then I see in the browser that account rest was changed:

> Payment [idPmnt=91, description=Shop 'Pirasmani', summ=50.25,
>   account=Account [idAcc=475, account=12345678901230, isLock=N,
>   rest=9950.25]]

But in database there is no changes in account rest. It steel is =10000.5.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't start and stop transactions in the DAO methods. All the code in the last section should be in a single transaction, which would allow you to

- work on attached entities, and have all the changes made on the account persisted automatically
- remove the unnecessary `cascade={CascadeType.MERGE}` on the association
- leave the database in a coherent state and not, as now, in a state where the payment has been created but the rest has not been decreased (which is why we use transactions in the first place).

That said, you persist a payment. Why would that cause any modification of its account? The only cascade you have is MERGE, and you're not doing any merge in the code.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.  Why shouldn't I start and stop transactions in the DAO methods? I found this standart code for DAO in the JPA examples. So I use one universal DAO.class for all entities. And, as I understand, JPA annotations make hole work for me with this universal DAO. I've thought that something wrong with my annotations. Is there other way how to resolve my problem without changing DAO or I need write specific DAO for each entity?

Comment: Because the whole point of a transaction is to guarantee ACIDity (Atomicity, Coherence, Isolation, Durability). You want your data to stay coherent: either the payment is created AND the rest is decreased, or none of those 2 operations is done. That's why transactions are used. If each of those operations is done in a single transaction, your database doesn't stay in a coherent state (as you just saw). Transactions should be demarcated by the service layer, not by the DAO layer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understant, but my teacher wouldn't very happy if I moved transactions in the service layer. And I know what is ACID very well. I've thought if I change first entity and second entity (mapped by Cascade annotation) than make persist for first entity so this is automatically change other enity in single transaction. Isn't this a main idia of JPA? And I know that it works good, for instance, for "OneToMany" if you create parent and add his new children, just make persist for parent. In that case no needs to code becouse of Cascade annotations. All stored in a single transaction.

Comment: Cascade.MERGE cascades the merge operation. You're not calling merge. And if your teacher is not happy about that, then choose another teacher, because he doesn't know what he's talking about. How would you handle a single transaction updating a Payment, inserting a Statistic, deleting a Debt, and sending a JMS message, if you demarcated transactions at the DAO layer? Your whole business logic can't be implemented by cascade annotations.